# Android reporting ANR on the CookieManager.getInstance()

Tags: android, cookies

I am facing an ANR issue when I try to get the instance of CookieManager in android.
As per the firebase this issue is mostly reported in android 11 and 12.

In my code I am just trying to get the instance of the cookie manager.

```
 try {
                cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               Logger.e(e, "Cannot init CookieManager");
            }
```

Below is the firebase logs for the same.

```
 main (native): tid=1 systid=9621 
    #00 pc 0x4c4ac libc.so (syscall + 28)
    #01 pc 0x47cc80 libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*) + 140)
    #02 pc 0x55d7f4 libart.so (artQuickGenericJniEndTrampoline + 1156)
    #03 pc 0x440564 libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline + 164)
    #04 pc 0x2ea2f58 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.webkit.WebViewLibraryLoader.loadNativeLibrary + 232)
    #05 pc 0x2e9fcd4 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass + 1300)
    #06 pc 0x2e9f11c memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider + 716)
    #07 pc 0x2e978e4 memfd:jit-zygote-cache (android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance + 36)
           at android.webkit.WebViewLibraryLoader.nativeLoadWithRelroFile(Native method)
           at android.webkit.WebViewLibraryLoader.loadNativeLibrary(WebViewLibraryLoader.java:214)
           at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:512)
           at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:348)
           at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding my cookieManager inside the coroutines.

```
class SetAcceptCookieUseCase(private val cookie: CookieManager) {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
     operator fun invoke(cookieAccepted : Boolean) {
         scope.launch{
             try {
                 cookie?.setAcceptCookie(cookieAccepted)
             } catch (e: Exception) {
                 Logger.e(e,"Cannot init CookieManager")
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager#setAcceptCookie(boolean)

cookies are enabled by default. we don't need to set it explicitly.